# ICMPv6 socket failed to create

Tags: c, sockets, ipv6, icmp

I am trying to send a ICMPV6 message to remote network, as an initial step I tried to create a ICMPv6 socket in a simple class (`SendICMPv6.c`) which contains the `winsock2`, `ws2tcpip`, `stdio` and `stdlib` headers. But I am unable to create socket. Could someone help What's wrong?

The code is:

```
WSADATA  wsaData;
int iResult = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData);
    if (iResult != 0) {
        wprintf(L"WSAStartup failed: %d\n", iResult);
        return 1;
    }
int fd = socket(AF_INET6, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_ICMPV6);
    if (fd < 0) {
        perror("creating socket failed");
    }
```

Can someone figure out the problem?

Comment: @aribeiro the code doesn't work, and thus it would be off-topic at Code Review.

Comment: @Pimgd, sorry, my bad!

Comment: @coredump: the OP mentioned winsock, which means the code is running on Windows, which does not have `errno`, you have to use `WSAGetLastError()` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you read the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740548(v=vs.85).aspx) carefully, there are few options you can check:

1. Can your OS create `SOCK_RAW` sockets?

   > If a Winsock service provider supports SOCK_RAW sockets for the AF_INET or AF_INET6 address families, the socket type of SOCK_RAW should be included in the [WSAPROTOCOL_INFO](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms741675.aspx) structure returned by [WSAEnumProtocols](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms741574.aspx) function for one or more of the available transport providers.
2. Are you running as an Administrator?

   > Therefore, only members of the Administrators group can create sockets of type SOCK_RAW on Windows 2000 and later.

You need to add more error checks in your code.  For instance, if [`socket()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740506.aspx) fails:

> If no error occurs, socket returns a descriptor referencing the new socket. Otherwise, a value of INVALID_SOCKET is returned, and a specific error code can be retrieved by calling [WSAGetLastError](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms741580.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

`SOCK_RAW` requires admin rights.  Is your app running in an elevated state?

When `socket()` fails, use `WSAGetLastError()` to find out why, eg:

```
WSADATA wsaData;
int iResult = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData);
if (iResult != 0) {
    printf("WSAStartup failed: %d\n", iResult);
    return 1;
}

SOCKET fd = socket(AF_INET6, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_ICMPV6);
if (fd == INVALID_SOCKET) {
    printf("creating socket failed: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
    return 1;
}
```